# How to click a href under div and span in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, href

In a wiki page having many pages listed, I am trying to click on a page which is a link. I am using:

By SelectPageName = By.cssSelector("a[href='/wiki/display/TS/Test']");

But i get:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href='/wiki/display/TS/Test']"}

The html structure is as mentioned in the screenshot below.

I looked through most of the questions posted in stackoverflow. But, nothing worked for me. I have tried using PartialLink and link also, and still no success. Please guide me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnMTB.png)

Comment: Hey, before moving ahead with digging into this question. Did you check the URL. In the image you have attached the URL is '/wiki/display/TS/Test' or you are looking for a different URL that exist on your page?

Comment: Hey Prateek, Yes, that's the URL('/wiki/display/TS/Test') I'm looking for.

Comment: But your css selector mentions '/wiki/display/TS/page3'. Both URLs are different. Please recheck the URL.

Comment: Oh you are right. 'Test' and 'Page3' refer to different pages that is listed in the wiki. I was trying locate both the pages. But, I am not able to locate any from my code.

Comment: If it is a public page which you are trying to automate. Is it possible for you to share it? That would help.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a public URL. Anything else that you think could help?

Comment: Ok np, have you tried waiting for the element first? can you please more of your code which is related to this element?

Comment: No. I am not doing that. Could that be a  cause?

Comment: Quite possible. Try adding some wait

Comment: Ok I'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: For href anchors, you should try to always use By.partialText or By.partialLinkText .  Refactor your question to ask it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some wait, this will wait for the element and will make sure enough time is given for the element to load, this is one of the most common reasons:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);           
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a[href='/wiki/display/TS/Test']"));
```

and if your motive is to click on the element, a better method to use is this :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[href='/wiki/display/TS/Test']")));
```

Above function will wait for element to be visible and enabled.

Please let me know if this does not work, we can dig deeper.